# root cause of java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

I was wondering what is the root cause of java.lang.StackOverflowError.
i know it occur when the methods are recursively called infinite times but what is the actual cause of the exception and what is the default stack size?

Comment: The default size is set by the VM, though you may set the size using the -Xss JVM parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily thrown only in case of recursive calls. It is thrown whenever the stack memory space is filled with typical data that are placed on stack: local variables, local parameters and so on.

Obviously, the chance of getting a stack overflow error grows with the size of the stack (how many method calls are there between the current method being executed and the root of the thread) and with the number of active threads.

But, as I mentioned, recursive calls are not the only cause for getting a large stack.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is this: the **stack size is fixed** at runtime, and VM provide no way to adjust it once the program runs. But **recursion depth is not fixed**, in many cases it depends on the input data. That is why recursion depth is sometimes such that not all stack frames fit in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

An stackoverflowerror occurs whenever a specific part of the memory ("the stack") runs out. Basically you have ran out of memory allocated to your program in general without asking for any additional memory so your program crashes.

Specifically the stack is used for all things related towards calling functions and threads so you could in theory you could even run out of memory by making a new thread (although you would first need to nearly fill it with function calls). Additionally the recursion does not need to be infinite just very large.

```
public int foo(int i){
    if (i=0)
       return 0;
    return (foo(i-1)+foo(i-1)%1000);
}
```

and then calling foo (10000) would result in a stackoverflow without being infinite.

If you are more interested in finding out about the stack I would suggest how recursion works within a more low level language such as assembly where you can really see what your machine is doing (note that learning this will take quite a lot of afford but will make you a better programmer ).

Answer (score 0):

if you check the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html)

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

now.. to know why a recursive method call is creating this error, you should know the mechanism of method calling in java.

to describe in simple sentence, when a method is called the information of method calling is pushed into a stack in the memory. when the method ends that means it is returned then the information is popped.  The stack size is not unlimited so when the memory overflows and you are trying to call another method (i.e pushing info of another method calls) it throws this error.

Now for infinite recursive method calls you are only pushing the into stack but as the methods are not finishing so you are not popping. so definitely the above case will occur..

i just tried to describe in easy language. To know more deeply check many helpful articles like [following](http://www.leepoint.net/JavaBasics/methods/methods-25-calls.html)